# What brand of frame has a star cutout behind the seat?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, bmx

What bmx bike has a star cut-out just behind the seat? sealed bb.

[image]

Comment: FYI, I believe this feature is called a seat stay bridge. On rim brake bikes, this is obviously where you put the rear brake. Here, the bridge is just for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same frame and it was a mirraco

Comment: Plausible - Mirraco appears to have a little 5 pointed star in many of their logos https://www.logolynx.com/topic/mirraco   Some further digging returns this thread which reinforces the suggestion.   https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=732551

Answer (score 1):

I think these were the old school Malvern Star bikes.

We used to ride rusty versions of these bikes at my Nana's caravan park on holidays.

Comment: @jaysun are you in Australia?    Malvern Star is an australian brand though I see them available in NZ recently.  They are a BSO level bike nowdays though used to be better.